# How to make IntelliJ use Java 8 for a Maven module instead of Java 11 at language level 8?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-11

I have a multi-module Maven project where sources are written for Java 8 and tests for Java 11.  I have both installed on my machine and made known to the IDE's.

When imported in Eclipse the source modules are connected with a Java 8 environment bound to a Java 8 JVM, and the test modules with a Java 8 environment bound to a Java 11 JVM as described by the maven-compiler-plugin settings.

When imported in IntelliJ **all modules are uncritically assigned** the Java 11 Project SDK and the language level is set to either 8 or 11 as described by the maven-compiler-plugin settings.

[image: intellij settings for module]

I would like for IntelliJ to behave like Eclipse (or at least I think I do) to ensure that the environment as seen from the IDE is exactly as it will be when deployed.

How do I tell IntelliJ to do this?

Comment: IDE does not use Maven configuration when set the JDKs for modules - so you can just set the JDK for each module individually: [Change module SDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#change-module-sdk).

Comment: @Andrey I found the same.  Do you know if this can be made the default behavior of the Maven importer?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So that IntelliJ does this by default instead

Comment: As mentnmioed initially, IDE does not set JDK based on pom.xml. If you want it to be different from the Project JDK, it should be changed manually for module.

Comment: @Andrey And manually is just what I would like to avoid, but instead having set automatically.  Raised with JetBrains.